# google custom search api return multiple titles. How should i detect link for appropriate title?

Tags: java, regex, search, google-custom-search

When i search with "the lion and the mouse" result i get as this format -

```
   "title": "The Lion & the Mouse",
   "title": "The Lion and the Mouse - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
   "title": "The Lion and the Mouse - ABCmouse.com Aesop's Fables Series ...",
      "title": "The Lion and the Mouse - ABCmouse.com Aesop's Fables Series",
   "title": "The Lion & the Mouse: Jerry Pinkney: 9780316013567: Amazon ...",
      "title": "The Lion & the Mouse: Jerry Pinkney: 9780316013567: Amazon.com: Books"
   "title": "The Lion & The Mouse - Aesop Fables - YouTube",
      "title": "The Lion & The Mouse - Aesop Fables",
   "title": "Story Arts | Aesop's ABC | The Lion and the Mouse",
   "title": "AesopFables.com - The Lion and the Mouse - General Fable collection",
   "title": "Aesop's Fables: The Lion and the Mouse",
   "title": "The Lion & the Mouse by Jerry Pinkney | 9780316013567 ...",
   "title": "The Lion and the Mouse â€“ Fable & Short Story Online",


www.read.gov/aesop/007.html
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_and_the_Mouse
www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPybpc-xuG0
www.amazon.com/The-Lion-Mouse-Jerry-Pinkney/dp/0316013560
www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzyvmC1FAt0
www.storyarts.org/library/aesops/stories/lion.html
www.aesopfables.com/cgi/aesop1.cgi?3&TheLionandtheMouse2
www.bbc.co.uk/learning/schoolradio/subjects/english/aesops_fables/17-24/lion_mouse
www.barnesandnoble.com/w/lion-the-mouse-jerry-pinkney/1101089622?ean=9780316013567
www.kidsworldfun.com/shortstories_lionandmouse.php
```

But i can not detect which title for which link sometimes titles are multiple for one link. How can i find one title for one link?

Source Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String stroy = "the lion ,the mouse";           

        String Key = "key";
        String Query = stroy.replace(" ", "%20");                

        URL url = new URL(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+Key+"&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q="+ Query +"&alt=json");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        int i=0;
        ArrayList<String> Links = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")){  

                //System.out.println(output);
                String link=output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));

                Links.add(link);
            } 

            if(output.contains("\"title\": \"")){              


                //String title = output.split("\"")[3];

                if(i>2){        
                Titles.add(output);

                }      
                i++;
            } 

        }

        for(int j=0; j<Titles.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(Titles.get(j).toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=0;j<Links.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(Links.get(j).toString());
        }
        conn.disconnect();

        }
    }
```

Comment: please show complete json response output.

Answer (score 0):

try to store title & link in the same block.
use json tool [Examples of JSON decoding](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)